# Ajax Toolkit to connect wave rest api

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rest-api, einstein-analytics, ajax-toolkit

I am trying to connect the wave rest API via AJAX Toolkit.

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="true">
 <script src="/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function ctrlwave(){ 
         var srest=sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}';
         sforce.connection.init('srest', 'https://xxxxxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/wave/query');
         var envelope = "q=load \"datsetname\";\nq = group q by ('Name', 'Wac.Cc');\nq = foreach q generate 'Name' as 'Name', 'Wac.Cc' as 'wac.Cc', count() as 'count';\nq = order q by ('Name' asc, 'Wac.Cc' asc);\nq = limit q 2000;";
         sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
                url : "https://xxxxxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/wave/query",
                requestHeaders: {"Authorization":"Bearer "+srest,"Content-Type":"application/json",}, 
                requestData: envelope,
                method: "POST",
                onSuccess : function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                   },
              onFailure : function(response) {
              alert("Failed" + response)
          }
   });
     }        
  </script>
<apex:form >
   <div>Wave TOOL</div>
   <apex:commandButton onclick="ctrlwave();" value="waveRet" id="theButton"/>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

I am getting error "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning. If your code isn't working, something else is going on.

Comment: Https error 401 unauthorized it is coming